# How does vim "syntax cluster" highlighting work (or why does this "syntax cluster" not work)?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

This is a repost from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65864654/how-does-vim-syntax-cluster-highlighting-work) at the suggestion of a user to this vim-specific forum.

I am trying to use a vim syntax file for highlighting a PyMOL script file and got into trouble with the "syntax cluster" definitions, the vim files are from https://github.com/speleo3/PyMol-syntax . The definitions that give trouble are:

```
syntax keyword pymolOperatorK  and or not
syntax match pymolOperator1 "[!|&,()?]"
syntax cluster pymolOperator contains=pymolOperator1,pymolOperatorK
...
hi def link pymolOperator Operator
```

When editing a PyMOL file (syntax file properly loaded and other parts properly highlighted), the keywords "and, or, not" are not properly highlighted.
However, if I add the following two lines, then the highlighting is working:

```
hi def link pymolOperator1 Operator
hi def link pymolOperatorK Operator
```

Basically, it looks like the "syntax cluster" part is not working.

There is another "syntax cluster" line defined, the "pymolString" group, which has the same issue, only after I add "hi def link" individually does the corresponding highlighting work.

I also tried to move the "syntax cluster" definition before the "syntax keyword" line, still did not work.

Any comments?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Cluster" is a logical unit. The text elements are still bound to ordinary syntax items, such as `pymolOperatorK`.

You must create highlighting links manually, e.g.

```
hi def link pymolOperatorK pymolOperator
hi def link pymolOperator1 pymolOperator
hi def link pymolOperator Operator
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That makes sense now.